# Given 2 multivariate datasets, identify records representing the same entity, which differ slightly

Tags: machine-learning, duplicates, fuzzy-comparison

Let's take the example of having 2 data sources, with data sizes "m" and "n" respectively. Both datasets are SQL tables having the same schema, but different data. Our goal is to "flag" fuzzy-matches (*between the datasets*) that are similar enough to consider "**identical**".

```
CREATE TABLE player(
    id Integer,
    fname VARCHAR(64),
    lname VARCHAR(64),
    birth_dt datetime,
    weight Integer
)
```

While the majority of total combinations (m*n) will not be matches, we would like to flag "similar" matches like the following:

```
{"fname": "John", "lname": "Smith", "birth_dt": "6/6/91", "weight": 220}
{"fname": "Jack", "lname": "Smith", "birth_dt": "6/6/91", "weight": 210}
```

Are there any tools (open-sourced or not) that do a great job of identifying and flagging these "matches"?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of "[record linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage)", and that keyword will help you find a big literature about the problem.

The open source, python library [dedupe](https://github.com/datamade/dedupe), provides one comprehensive approach.

Comment: We actually used Dedupe, and it turned out to be a great solution! Leaving this open to encourage additional answers...

Comment: In the future, please disclose your affiliation with dedupe when suggesting it where the question isn't already about it.